# How to create a dataframe from images list and labels numpy array

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, neural-network

For image processing I need a dataframe to put into my model. The problem is the images I have in seperate folder, and I have labels for them in a different csv file. I read all the images with cv2.imread and I create a list that are Grayscale and 32x32 sized. I have 50.000 images like this:
[image: List of images]

And I read the csv file and one hot encode them and save them as numpy array. There are 10 classes so my numpy array has 50.000 rows for each image and 10 columns for each class:

[image: Labels numpy array]

So my question is how can I create a dataframe and X, y of that data frame so that I can put it into my model as follows:

```
#Create Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), input_shape=X.shape[1:] ))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer="adam", metrics =['accuracy'])

#Now instead of validation_dataset and train_dataset below I need to put my own datasets..
model_fit= model.fit(X,y, batch_size=32, epochs=3, validation_split=0.2, verbose=1 )
```

Comment: why you don't simply extract the images from the data frame and use them as image labels?

Comment: I don't have a dataframe yet. I have images in a folder which is not in a form of list and a seperate csv file that tells which image is what. And that is now a one hot encoded numpy array